How to prove a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ cannot be both open and closed in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$?
How to prove a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ cannot be both open and closed in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$?
It seems that this result is obvious, but it is not that easy to write a rigorous proof.
Assume there is such a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, which is both open and closed in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$. I tried to find some contradictions but failed.
There is a similar question here, but it only deals with $\mathbf R$. How to prove this result in $\mathbf R^n$?
Could you help me?
Answer HackR's comment:
This question is different from the question in this link.  In that question, the questioner says "I know that you can find a lot of posts here where people tried to solve this task. But I want to do this with help of the hint our teacher gave us". In my question, I accept all the methods to solve this task. So they are different questions.

Are you familiar with the notion of connectedness?

@DavideMasi How to use connectedness to solve this problem?

@HackR in that question, the questioner says "I know that you can find a lot of posts here where people tried to solve this task. But I want to do this with help of the hint our teacher gave us". In my question, I accept all the methods to solve this task. So they are different questions.

By definition, a topological space $X$ is connected if $\emptyset$ and $X$ are the only subsets of $X$ which are both open and closed. So your question is a consequence of $\mathbb R^n$ being connected.

Note that:

A subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open iff. $\forall x\in X \text{ } \exists \epsilon>0 \text{ } (B_\epsilon (x) \subseteq X)$
A subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed iff. it contains all of its limit points.
Given a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and an $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x$ is a limit point of $X$ iff. for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $y\in X$ such that $y\in B_\epsilon (x)\setminus \{x\}$
A subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded iff. $\exists\epsilon>0$ $\forall x\in X \left\| x \right\| \le \epsilon$

We may use the fact that we are talking about bounded sets to our advantage:
Here is an outline of a proof, which shows that any bounded clopen subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is empty:
By way of contradiction, suppose $X$ is nonempty.
First, take the supremum $s$ of all real numbers $R\ge 0$ such that $\left\|x\right\|=R$ for some $x\in X$. Now, if $s$ is zero, this immediately leads to a contradiction (exercise: why?). So, suppose $s>0$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $r\in X$ such that $\left\| r \right\|>s-\epsilon$.
Then, show that there exists a limit point $t$ of $X$ such that $\left\|t\right\|=s$. This can be done by contradiction. Suppose that no such limit point exists, i.e., for any such $t$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta (t) \setminus \{t\}$ contains no point in $X$. Show that this contradicts that $s$ is a supremum of the magnitudes of the elements of $X$.
Thus, since $t$ is a limit point of $X$, and $X$ is closed, $t\in X$. From there, show that $X$ is not open, which is a contradiction.
And thus, $X$ must be empty.
And we may write $Q.E.D.$

If $s$ is zero, then $X={\mathbf{0}}$ which is not open. Here is a contradiction. (Just do that exercise.)

Your answer is great! If we remove the condition the subset is bounded, can we use this method to prove a non-empty proper subset of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ cannot be both open and closed in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$?

Honestly, I am not sure. I do, however, think that we probably can't use this method, as the reason why this worked is explicitly because of the boundedness of $X$, which allowed us to find a supremum for the norms. If the set is unbounded, however, then there is clearly no supremum. So, we likely have to use something else, such as the notion of connectedness. However, if possible, I would like to see how we could do something like what I did in my proof if we had instead considered general proper subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable than I am could help out here.

Consider the case we remove the condition the subset is bounded. The supremum can be modified in this way: There exist $\mathbf{x}\in X$ and $\mathbf{y}\in X^{c}$ and $s=\sup{t\in[0,1]|(1-t)\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{y}\in X}$. If $s=0$, $\mathbf{x}$ is a limit point of $X^{C}$, $X^{C}$ is closed, and $\mathbf{x}\in X^{C}$ (but $\mathbf{x}\in X$, here is a contradiction). If $s\neq0$, $\mathbf{z}=(1-s)\mathbf{x}+s\mathbf{y}$ is a limit point of $X$, $X$ is closed, $\mathbf{z}\in X$, $X$ is not open (but $X$ is open, here is a contradiction).

This method, which just modifies the supremum, is very similar to your method, which solves the bounded case. Amazing!

Nice! In hindsight, I should have thought a little harder before commenting I suppose...
The best thing about this method is that it works for normed vector spaces in general.

You can use the same way as in $\Bbb R$. Let us assume that a non empty subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is bounded, opened and closed.Let us call it $A$.
Considere $\{\lVert x\rVert, x\in A\}$. By definition, it is a bounded subset of $\Bbb R$, so it has an upper bound, say $M$. As $A$ is closed, $\exists x_M\in A, \lVert x_0\rVert=M$.
But as $A$ is opened, its complement $\complement A$ is closed. And by definition, $B=\{x\in \Bbb R^n, \lVert x\rVert>M\}\subset\complement A$.
Consider now an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. The set $C_\varepsilon=\{x\in\Bbb R^n, M<\lVert x\rVert<M+\varepsilon\}$ is non empty. Whatever the norm used, it is enough to increase one coordinate of $x_0$ by a fraction of $\varepsilon$ to find one element. And $C_\varepsilon\subset B$. That is enough to prove $x_0 \in\overline B$. But as $B\subset \complement A$ and $\complement A$ is closed, that means that $x_0\in\complement A$.
This leads to a contradiction. So $A$ cannot exist. $Q.E.D.$
